# pygame.sprite.spritecollideany not colliding?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

in a platformer game i'm dabbling with, i'm having an issue where the player controlled unit stops briefly and then continues to fall.

a brief description - a unit that is in the falling state accelerates as it falls. i use its current velocity to determine if it will collide with the given object.

the way i would expect this to act is in a state of freefall (the falling state), pg.sprite.spritecollideany would return false until it hit something (or was projected to hit something). at that point, it would always be hitting something and thus return yes and no longer fall.

what actually happens is as soon as there's going to be a collision, the unit stops briefly, but then returns to its falling state until it hits something else and this repeats.

i'm really at a loss for why this happens

here's the relevant code. the important code i think is the up_down_collision function

```
class Unit(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def create_self_rect(self): 
        self.rect = pg.Rect(50, 50, 10, 20)  

    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
        self.y_vel = 0
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.jumping_velocity = 3
        self.gravity = .1  
        self.jumped = 0
        self.state = {}
        self.state['jumping'] = False
        self.state['falling'] = True
        self.state['grounded'] = False
        self.create_self_rect()

    def update_rect(self):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 20)

    def change_state(self, new_state):
        for state in self.state:
            self.state[state] = False
        self.state[new_state] = True

    def return_state(self):
        for state in self.state:
            if self.state[state]:
                return state

    def update(self):
        self.left_right_collision(worlds.all_obstacles, self.x_vel) #worlds is a seperate module that holds all the collidables. nothing special
        self.up_down_collision(worlds.all_obstacles, self.y_vel)
        if self.return_state() is 'falling':
            self.falling_state()
        if self.return_state() is 'grounded':
            self.y_vel = 0
        self.update_position()
        self.update_rect()

    def update_position(self):
        self.x += self.x_vel
        self.y += self.y_vel

    def falling_state(self):
        time = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.y_vel = self.y_vel + \
            (((time - self.jumped) / 1000) * self.gravity)

    def up_down_collision(self, collidables, velocity):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, velocity)
        if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, collidables):
            collidables = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidables, False)
            for platform in collidables:
                if abs(velocity) == velocity:
                    self.rect.move_ip(0, -velocity)
                    self.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top
                    self.change_state('grounded')
                else:
                    self.rect.move_ip(0, -velocity)
                    self.rect.top = platform.rect.bottom
                    self.y_vel = 0
        else:
            self.change_state('falling')

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_pos, size): #startpos, size are tuples
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = start_pos[0]
        self.y = start_pos[1]
        self.width = size[0]
        self.height = size[1]
        self.rect = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

pg.draw.rect(game_screen, (200, 200, 200), player.rect)
lp = pf.Platform((300, 800), (500, 10))
pg.draw.rect(game_screen, (200, 200, 200), lp.rect)
hp = pf.Platform((800, 700), (200, 10))
pg.draw.rect(game_screen, (200, 200, 200), hp)
base = pf.Platform((0, 900), (1680, 200))
pg.draw.rect(game_screen, (200, 200, 200), base)
wall = pf.Platform((1500, 700), (50, 300))
pg.draw.rect(game_screen, (200, 200, 200), wall)
worlds.all_obstacles = [lp, hp, base, wall]
```

also please excuse the poor code. it's pretty embarrassing to post!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in `update`:

```
if self.return_state() is 'falling':
                     # ^ should be == not is
```

You are testing identity, not equivalence.

Comment: sorry! updated the code to show what return state is. even if i make the change you suggested, the unit keeps falling. please let me know if you need any more information! its all a bit kludgey and im kind of embarrassed to show more!

Comment: Have you put in any `print`s to determine the state? Tested parts of the program in isolation?